# JavaScript: add or subtract from number in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that looks like "(3) New stuff" where 3 can be any number.
I would like to add or subtract to this number.

I figured out the following way:

```
var thenumber = string.match((/\d+/));
thenumber++;
string = string.replace(/\(\d+\)/ ,'('+ thenumber +')');
```

Is there a more elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Gumbo was on the right track

```
"(42) plus (1)".replace(/\((\d+)\)/g, function(a,n){ return "("+ (+n+1) +")"; });
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way:

```
string = string.replace(/\((\d+)\)/ , function($0, $1) { return "(" + (parseInt($1, 10) + 1) + ")"; });
```

Answer (score 1):

Short of extending the String object, it looks good to me.

```
String.prototype.incrementNumber = function () {
  var thenumber = string.match((/\d+/));
  thenumber++;
  return this.replace(/\(\d+\)/ ,'('+ thenumber +')');
}
```

Usage would then be:

```
alert("(2) New Stuff".incrementNumber());
```

Comment: Unlike Array, I don't think extending string is that bad. Since how many times do you iterate over String objects?

Comment: I like this approach as well, myself.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your method is the best elegant you can have for following reasons:

- since the input is not a "clean" number, you do need to involve some sort of string parser. Using regular expressions is the very code-efficient method to do it
- by looking at the code, it's clear what it does

short of wrapping this into a function, I don't think there's much more to be done

Answer (score 1):

As galets says, I don't think your solution is a bad one but here is a function that will add a specified value to a number in a specified position in a string.

```
var str = "fluff (3) stringy 9 and 14 other things";

function stringIncrement( str, inc, start ) {
    start = start || 0;
    var count = 0;
    return str.replace( /(\d+)/g, function() {
        if( count++ == start ) {
            return(
                arguments[0]
                .substr( RegExp.lastIndex )
                .replace( /\d+/, parseInt(arguments[1])+inc )
            );
        } else {
            return arguments[0];
        }
    })
}

// fluff (6) stringy 9 and 14 other things :: 3 is added to the first number
alert( stringIncrement(str, 3, 0) );

// fluff (3) stringy 6 and 14 other things :: -3 is added to the second number
alert( stringIncrement(str, -3, 1) );

// fluff (3) stringy 9 and 24 other things :: 10 is added to the third number
alert( stringIncrement(str, 10, 2) );
```